# Using NodeJS Express, how to properly make a GET call to MySQL in ReactJS?

Tags: mysql, node.js, rest, reactjs, redux

I have a server running up on Tomcat Apache with a MySQL. For my project, I am using ReactJS + Redux, and NodeJS Express. How do I properly make a GET call to the Tomcat Apache?

In my actions.js for Redux:

```
  callGet() {
    var data = {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'time': 'TESTING'
    }

    var init = {
      method: 'GET',
      mode: 'cors',
      header: data,
    };

    return function(dispatch) {
      dispatch({
        type: 'CALL_GET'
      });

      fetch('http://www.localhost:8080/form/post/create/', init)
        .then(result=>result.json())
        .then(users=>{
          console.log(users);
        });
      }
    }
```

And for my Node.js Express setup:

```
app.use('/', function (req, res, next) {
  res.sendFile(path.resolve('client/index.html'));

  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
  next();
});
```

yet with the `Cannot GET /` on the page, I am still getting an error:

`Failed to load resource: http://localhost:3005/ the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)`

What could be the issue or what am I missing? Can't seem to spot the error. Thank you for the help.

Comment: What about `path.resolve(__dirname, 'client/index.html')`? Also, calling `res.sendFile` should be the last thing you do. Setting headers after this and calling `next()` doesn't make sense.

Comment: @DavidGilbertson Sorry but what should be the correct order then? Also is making a call to server-side Java from ReactJS possible?